# Unique model field in Django and case sensitivity (postgres)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, unique

Consider the following situation: -

Suppose my app allows users to create the states / provinces in their
country. Just for clarity, we are considering only ASCII characters
here.

In the US, a user could create the state called "Texas". If this app
is being used internally, let's say the user doesn't care if it is
spelled "texas" or "Texas" or "teXas"

But importantly, the system should prevent creation of "texas" if
"Texas" is already in the database.

If the model is like the following:

```
class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
```

The uniqueness would be case-sensitive in postgres; that is, postgres
would allow the user to create both "texas" and "Texas" as they are
considered unique.

What can be done in this situation to prevent such behavior. How does
one go about providing case-**insenstitive** uniqueness with Django and
Postgres

Right now I'm doing the following to prevent creation of case-
insensitive duplicates.

```
class CreateStateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        try:
            State.objects.get(name__iexact=name)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return name
        raise forms.ValidationError('State already exists.')

    class Meta:
        model = State
```

There are a number of cases where I will have to do this check and I'm not keen on having to write similar iexact checks everywhere.

Just wondering if there is a built-in or
better way? Perhaps db_type would help? Maybe some other solution exists?

Comment: I think you're already doing it right. At least that's the way i do it with tags, so my tag cloud doesn't end up with "tag", "Tag", and "TAG" all right next to each other.

Comment: Yes but here Django's built-in unique is not being of much help, is it? After all I'm having to do the unique checks myself everywhere.

Comment: I would code the app to ensure that the string entered the database only in lowercase.  Then check against that.

Comment: I would rather let the user keep whatever case he wants to keep.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could define a custom model field derived from `models.CharField`.
This field could check for duplicate values, ignoring the case.

Custom fields documentation is here http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/

Look at http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/files.py for an example of how to create a custom field by subclassing an existing field.

You could use the citext module of PostgreSQL https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html

If you use this module, the the custom field could define "db_type" as CITEXT for PostgreSQL databases.

This would lead to case insensitive comparison for unique values in the custom field.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, and is seems more Django-istic than other solutions mentioned here.

Comment: see my answer below for the explicit steps

Comment: As of Django 1.11, `CICharField` is now part of Django. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/43812440/1089026

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively you can change the default Query Set Manager to do case insensitive look-ups on the field.  In trying to solve a similar problem I came across:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/305/

Code pasted here for convenience:

```
from django.db.models import Manager
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

class CaseInsensitiveQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def _filter_or_exclude(self, mapper, *args, **kwargs):
        # 'name' is a field in your Model whose lookups you want case-insensitive by default
        if 'name' in kwargs:
            kwargs['name__iexact'] = kwargs['name']
            del kwargs['name']
        return super(CaseInsensitiveQuerySet, self)._filter_or_exclude(mapper, *args, **kwargs)

# custom manager that overrides the initial query set
class TagManager(Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return CaseInsensitiveQuerySet(self.model)

# and the model itself
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(maxlength=50, unique=True, db_index=True)

    objects = TagManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: This approach won't work for compound queries like name__in=[] or related__name=.

Answer (score 7):

a very simple solution:

```
class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def clean(self):
        self.name = self.name.capitalize()
```

Comment: If the name contains two words (e.g. "South Dakota"), this would convert the second to lowercase. With a name, you probably want to use `title()`.

Answer (score 7):

Explicit steps for Mayuresh's answer:

1. in postgres do: CREATE EXTENSION citext;
2. in your models.py add:

   ```
   from django.db.models import fields

   class CaseInsensitiveTextField(fields.TextField):
       def db_type(self, connection):
           return "citext"
   ```

   reference: https://github.com/zacharyvoase/django-postgres/blob/master/django_postgres/citext.py
3. in your model use: name = CaseInsensitiveTextField(unique=True)

Answer (score 6):

On the Postgres side of things, a functional unique index will let you enforce unique values without case. citext is also noted, but this will work with older versions of PostgreSQL and is a useful technique in general.

Example:

```
# create table foo(bar text);
CREATE TABLE
# create unique index foo_bar on foo(lower(bar));
CREATE INDEX
# insert into foo values ('Texas');
INSERT 0 1
# insert into foo values ('texas');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "foo_bar"
```

Comment: I have tried this and can confirm it works. But the answer by Mayuresh allows me to live within Django.

Comment: Well, you should always enforce your constraints in the database as well.

Comment: What's a good way to enforce this 'automatically' at database level after Django has created models. I'm asking for a scripted way of doing this instead of manually editing db after django's `syncdb`

Answer (score 5):

Besides already mentioned option to override save, you can simply store all text in lower case in database and capitalize them on displaying.

```
class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        self.name = self.name.lower()
        super(State, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error now when I have the same text, how can I instead display the error on the page, instead of getting **"IntegrityError at /add_category/
UNIQUE constraint failed: theblog_category.name"?**

Answer (score 3):

You can use lookup='iexact' in UniqueValidator on serializer, like this:

```
class StateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    name = serializers.CharField(validators=[
    UniqueValidator(
        queryset=models.State.objects.all(),lookup='iexact'
    )]
```

django version: 1.11.6

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a postgres-specific solution, you can create a unique index on the field with `upper()` to enforce uniqueness at the database level, then create a custom `Field` mixin that overrides `get_lookup()` to convert case-sensitive lookups to their case-insensitive versions. The mixin looks like this:

```
class CaseInsensitiveFieldMixin:
    """
    Field mixin that uses case-insensitive lookup alternatives if they exist.
    """

    LOOKUP_CONVERSIONS = {
        'exact': 'iexact',
        'contains': 'icontains',
        'startswith': 'istartswith',
        'endswith': 'iendswith',
        'regex': 'iregex',
    }

    def get_lookup(self, lookup_name):
        converted = self.LOOKUP_CONVERSIONS.get(lookup_name, lookup_name)
        return super().get_lookup(converted)
```

And you use it like this:

```
from django.db import models


class CICharField(CaseInsensitiveFieldMixin, models.CharField):
    pass


class CIEmailField(CaseInsensitiveFieldMixin, models.EmailField):
    pass


class TestModel(models.Model):
    name = CICharField(unique=True, max_length=20)
    email = CIEmailField(unique=True)
```

You can read more about this approach [here](http://concisecoder.io/2018/10/27/case-insensitive-fields-in-django-models/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by overwriting the Model's save method - see the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods). You'd basically do something like:

```
class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        if State.objects.get(name__iexact = self.name):
            return
        else:
            super(State, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

Also, I may be wrong about this, but the upcoming model-validation SoC branch will allow us to do this more easily.

Comment: This is essentially the same as what I am already doing. In fact, they way I am doing it right now is better than handling it within save.

Comment: On a second read, you're right. AFAIK, using the forms' validation would be the best way to go (as of now) - unless the data is not being inserted via a form :).

Comment: It's totally possible for data to not be inserted via a form! especially if you are using a third-party app.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from suhail worked for me without the need to enable citext, pretty easy solution only a clean function and instead of capitalize I used `upper()`. Mayuresh's solution also works but changed the field from `CharField` to `TextField`.

```
class State(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def clean(self):
        self.name = self.name.upper()
```