# django model with unique combination of two fields

Tags: python, django, migration

I have a django model as below

```
class MySubject(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50)
    description=models.TextField(blank=True)
    slug=models.SlugField(editable=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="MySubjects"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.name=self.name.strip()
        self.slug=slugify(self.name)
        super(MySubject,self).save(*args,**kwargs)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('subject_detail',(),{'slug':self.slug})
```

I need to make the creator+ name unique ,sothat I can call

```
subject,status=MySubject.objects.get_or_create(name__iexact=name.strip(),creator= request.user,defaults={'name':name,'description':name,'creator':request.user})
```

Is the following ,the right way to do this?

```
class MySubject(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
        creator = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)
        description=models.TextField(blank=True)
        slug=models.SlugField(editable=False)

        class Meta: 
            verbose_name_plural="MySubjects"
            unique_together = ('name', 'creator',)
         ...
```

I guess I have to do a `migration` using `south` after making the change..Do I have to do `schemamigration` alone or do I have to do a `datamigration`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a unique constraint is a schema migration. However, if you have existing data that would cause an integrity error, you would need a data migration, as well.

If you really want case-insensitive unique constraint, it's a little more complicated:

[Case insensitive unique model fields in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773341/case-insensitive-unique-model-fields-in-django)

see also: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14564

If you always use `get_or_create` with iexact, you may be ok. But, you should not manually create two with name as "foo" and "fOo", because, this would be allowed and then your call to get_or_create would cause a MultipleObjectsReturned .. if I'm thinking correctly.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. how do I do the datamigration for this?I can add a value for creator in the forwards() method ,but how do I set the uniqueness for each record?

Comment: I know it may be heresy; but, I've never liked south and don't really know how to use it.