# Validating a model field to be unique as lower case

Tags: django, django-models

I needed to validate a model field to be unique as lower case, but without actually saving the model field in lower case; e.g. if someone has already taken the username 'david', then the username 'David' would not be available. I tried various things, and eventually ended up doing the following:

```
def _perform_unique_checks(self, unique_checks):
    errors = {}

    for model_class, unique_check in unique_checks:

        lookup_kwargs = {}
        for field_name in unique_check:
            f = self._meta.get_field(field_name)
            lookup_value = getattr(self, f.attname)
            if lookup_value is None:
                continue
            if f.primary_key and not self._state.adding:
                continue
            lookup_kwargs[str(field_name)] = lookup_value

        if len(unique_check) != len(lookup_kwargs):
            continue

        if 'username' in lookup_kwargs:
            lookup_kwargs['username'] = lookup_kwargs['username'].lower()

        qs = model_class._default_manager.filter(**lookup_kwargs)

        model_class_pk = self._get_pk_val(model_class._meta)
        if not self._state.adding and model_class_pk is not None:
            qs = qs.exclude(pk=model_class_pk)
        if qs.exists():
            if len(unique_check) == 1:
                key = unique_check[0]
            else:
                key = NON_FIELD_ERRORS
            errors.setdefault(key, []).append(
                self.unique_error_message(model_class, unique_check))
```

... which works, but feels a little convoluted to me. I wondered whether any there's a more succinct way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried filtering on field_name__iexact, to do a case insensitive match?

The iregex, icontains and iexact filters should be able to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can user the ***clean*** for this functionality (triggered when trying to validate a form):

```
def clean__field_name(self):
```

Also, you can add a `unique=True` constraint to the field in question. Then do a `Try/Except` during save to catch any `IntegrityError` which will tell you that the field is not unique. The database and model should do this work for you instead of trying to code around it.

Also see [Case insensitive unique model fields in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773341/case-insensitive-unique-model-fields-in-django)

With more detail (database type, copy of model, are you using a Form?), I can expand on this answer.