# update the same group if group name clashes

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can i update the same group if the name of group user wants to create matches with already created group? If i want to update instead of showing error where should i work on? Is it on validate function or create function?

Here is my serializer

```
class DeviceGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(source='token', format='hex', read_only=True)
    devices = DeviceIdSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DeviceGroup
        fields = ['id','name', 'devices',]

    def validate(self, data):
        errors = {}
        try:
            name = data['name']
            if not bool(name):
                #empty or null
                errors['name'] = 'Name cannot be empty'
        except KeyError:
            if not (self.instance and bool(self.instance.name)):
                errors['name'] = 'Name is required'

        if len(data.get('devices', [])) == 0:
            errors['devices'] = 'Device(s) should be specified.'

        if bool(errors):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(errors)
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # for create - there is always name; we have already checked that in validation
        # TODO Further check for group-name clash - if yes, update the same group
        owner = validated_data['owner']
        name = validated_data['name']
        group = DeviceGroup.objects.create(owner=owner, name=name)

        tokens = [d['token'] for d in validated_data['devices'] ]
        BaseDevice.objects.filter(token__in=tokens, owner=owner).update(group=group)
        return group

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # for update - there may or may not be name
        # if it does, it refers rename

        owner = validated_data['owner']
        name = validated_data.get('name', None)
        if not name is None:
            instance.update(name=name)

        tokens = [d['token'] for d in validated_data['devices'] ]
        BaseDevice.objects.filter(token__in=tokens, owner=owner).update(group=instance)
        return instance
```

Comment: Do you want `DeviceGroup` updated or `BaseDevice`?

Comment: If i have already a group named Important and i again create a group for device 'device2' then the device2 should be moved to the same group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`update_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create):

> A convenience method for updating an object with the given kwargs,
>   creating a new one if necessary. The defaults is a dictionary of
>   (field, value) pairs used to update the object.

Based on what you've shared, this would look something like the following, assuming you want to update the owner on `DeviceGroup`, if a `DeviceGroup` with the given `name` already exists:

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # for create - there is always name; we have already checked that in validation
        # TODO Further check for group-name clash - if yes, update the same group
        owner = validated_data['owner']
        name = validated_data['name']

        # created is a boolean telling us if a new DeviceGroup was created
        group, created = DeviceGroup.objects.update_or_create(name=name, defaults={'owner': owner})

        tokens = [d['token'] for d in validated_data['devices'] ]
        BaseDevice.objects.filter(token__in=tokens, owner=owner).update(group=group)
        return group
```

Comment: If i have update function, is it better to handle the name clash in create function or update ?

Comment: I have device called device1, device2 where device 1 is in Important group and when i clicked device2 and create a new group Important, the device2 should move to already created Important group instead of creating another group with same name

Comment: I had tried update_or_create but got an error of TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'

Comment: Sorry it was fault in mine code. It is working now. One question, though, if i now create a group Important then the device will be moved to already created group called Important instead of creating another Important group. But if i create a group important, it creates a new group. How to handle uppercase lowercase issue?

Comment: The quickest way to solve that would be to do something like `group_exists = DeviceGroup.objects.filter(name__iexact=name).exists()` or use a `try:catch` block, where you try to get the `DeviceGroup` (with `name__iexact`), if `DeviceGroup.DoesNotExist` is raised, just create it. You can also look at some [more options here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773341/case-insensitive-unique-model-fields-in-django), but they're a bit more complex than just modifying your query.

Comment: I understand the point and also thanks for the informative solution.