# How can I make a field case insensitive and unique only?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to add object to my models that are unique and case insensitive so if I add 'car' first and then I try to add 'cAr' it should return an error. I don't know how to that, though.
How can I make this happen?

This is the model:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is the serializer:

```
class FoodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Food
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Read that article - https://concisecoder.io/2018/10/27/case-insensitive-fields-in-django-models/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Case insensitive unique model fields in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773341/case-insensitive-unique-model-fields-in-django)

Comment: @marmeladze None of those things seem to change anything in this case

Comment: Which DB are you using? If PostgreSQL you could use CIText 
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#citext-fields

Answer (score 1):

You can Make your custom LowerCharField and Use it in your Models Just import this class
and car and Car can be checked for uniqueness.
Here is my solution.

```
 class LowerCharField(with_metaclass(models.SubfieldBase, models.CharField)):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.is_lowercase = kwargs.pop('lowercase', False)
            super(LowerCharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
        def get_prep_value(self, value):
            value = super(LowerCharField, self).get_prep_value(value)
            if self.is_lowercase:
                return value.lower()
            return value
```

And You can do this way

```
class Food(models.Model):
    name =LowerCharField(max_length=128, lowercase=True, null=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

If you want further customization like you may take any input from user i.e car or CAR at the end you may convert to lower and check for uniqueness.