# Django: saving unique value without duplicate it

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I'm trying to save unique name in the database but the problem I can save the same with different letters, for example I can save (IT, it, iT, It) I don't want to save it like that.

**Model:**

```
class Service(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127, unique=True, null=False, blank=False) # that field
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        "accounts.User",
        on_delete=SET_NULL,
        blank=False,
        null=True,
        related_name="service_created_by",
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
```

Comment: does this answer your question - [Case insensitive unique model fields in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773341/case-insensitive-unique-model-fields-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution:

```py
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    ....

    def clean(self):
        self.name = self.name.capitalize()
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, this one not working for me i tried to save 
Data, DATA, daTa, and django save it.

Answer (score 0):

this one helped me

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    ....

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(Lower("name"), name="unique_name"),
        ]

    def clean(self):
        self.name = self.name.capitalize()
```

Comment: you re not getting this error `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given` ?