# Validating two fields at the same time

Tags: django, django-models

I am looking at this piece of documentation:

[cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

The documentation explains how field dependency can be done, but I have a slightly different problem:

Say I have a model with two fields:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And say that one of the two fields is hidden, so the modelform looks like so:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        ...

        widgets = {'field2': forms.HiddenImput()}
```

Now, when the user fills out the form, I then (on `clean_field1`) also fill `field2`. Now, I want to report any error that happens to `field2` as an error about `field1`. This is because at the moment, the user does not know what he did wrong!

What I tried to do was, in the ModelForm definition:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(MyModelForm, self).clean()
    # Do something here
    return cleaned_data
```

As this is what is presented on the Django page. However, the problem is that when the `clean` method is executed, the dictionary `self.errors` is empty, so I don't know what to do...

Comment: So field2 can only be filled in the `clean_field2` method? Do you have the value of field2 before the form get filled? Is there any problem with raising the error in form instead of field?

Comment: Currently, yes, field2 only gets filled by the clean_field2 method. The value before that is irrelevant (it could be set, for example, to a default value, but currently it is not). I don't understand the question "Is there any problem with raising the error in form instead of field?"

Comment: you are filling `field2` in `clean_field1` right? Do you have to fill it AFTER validating `field1` or you just use the value of field1 to fill field2?

Comment: I fill it in the clean_field1 method, which is called, if I am correct, after the automatic validations of field1

Comment: Do you have to fill it after cleaning? Thats my question. IF you are just using the value to create field2 value let me know so I can post an answer

Comment: I am filling it *during* the cleaning, but I first clean field1, then field2. So the value I fill still gets validated (against duplicates).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about my answer. However, let's assume that you are using the `field1` data in order to generate `field2` value. You can generate it using a custom method and assign it to the field in the `__init__` method. Which will give you a good way to cleaning the two fields later.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # now lets generate field2 data using field1 data.. 
        self.data['field2'] = self.field[1] * 154220

    class Meta:
        widgets = {'field2': forms.HiddenInput()}    


    def clean_field1(self):
        ## Here you can do validation for field1 only.
        ## Do it like field2 is not exisited. 


    def clean_field2(self):
        ## Here you can do validation for field2 only.
        ## Do it like field1 is not exisited. 

    def clean(self):
        """
        In here you can validate the two fields
        raise ValidationError if you see anything goes wrong. 
        for example if you want to make sure that field1 != field2
        """
        field1 = self.cleaned_data['field1']
        field2 = self.cleaned_data['field2']

        if field1 == field2:
            raise ValidationError("The error message that will not tell the user that field2 is wrong.")

        return self.cleaned_data
```

---

**Update**

In case you want the `clean` method to raise the error in a specific field:

> Note that any errors raised by your Form.clean() override will not be
>   associated with any field in particular. They go into a special
>   “field” (called **all**), which you can access via the
>   non_field_errors() method if you need to. If you want to attach errors
>   to a specific field in the form, you need to call add_error().

So from Django documentation you can use `add_error()` to do what you want to achieve.

The code can be in this way

```
def clean(self):
    """
    In here you can validate the two fields
    raise ValidationError if you see anything goes wrong. 
    for example if you want to make sure that field1 != field2
    """
    field1 = self.cleaned_data['field1']
    field2 = self.cleaned_data['field2']

    if field1 == field2:
        # This will raise the error in field1 errors. not across all the form
        self.add_error("field1", "Your Error Message")

    return self.cleaned_data
```

Note that the above method is new with Django 1.7 and above.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error

Comment: The problem is that now, when there is an error in field2 (which is hidden), the form will show a nice error. For example, if I demand that field2 is unique, I want that error to propagate to field 1 (which the user can edit) from field 2 (which he cannot, but gets filled automatically). Some justification: field2 is simply a slugged version of field1, and I want field2 to be unique. If the user fills a form once with field1="Foo" and once with "foo", that's not unique enough.

Comment: Oh, and another thing: self.data['field2'] = self.field[1] * 154220 in my case raises an exception: This QueryDict instance is immutable...

Comment: Sorry, but your update does *not* address my question. What I am asking is: If `field2` **raises** an exception, how can this be shown in `field1` in the form? I know that I can add an error in the `clean` function, but that is not what I want to do. I want field2's errors to "appear" as field1's errors.

Comment: @5xum I think you are looking here for hint not a solution. Your first question is how to set fields data in the init method (Google it) and the other one use `add_error()` method in `clean_field2()` method, and everything should be fine. Think about the form as an object with attributes. You can after all cleaning move the list of errors for `field2` and append it to `field1` many solutions can be done.

Comment: Try `self.fields['field2'] = ...`