# Django is treating same field which are lowercase and upper case as 2 different entities

Tags: django

I am creating models in django and then entering data in admin panel

```
class Song(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=30,validators=[alphanumeric]).title()
  slug=models.SlugField(default="",blank=True,null=False,db_index=True)
  artist = models.CharField(max_length=30,validators=[alphanumeric])
  genre = models.CharField(max_length=30,validators=[alphanumeric])
  language = models.CharField(max_length=30,validators=[alphanumeric])
  image = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
```

But the issue is when I am entering "AceHunter" or "acehunter" as artist it is treating as different artists although I want them as one....

Please can someone help me what error I am making?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31724766/2314347 this is nice solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PostgreSQL [CIText](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#citext-fields) which is case-insensitive text field or validate like this:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
class Song(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=30,validators=[alphanumeric]).title()
  slug=models.SlugField(default="",blank=True,null=False,db_index=True)
  artist = models.CharField(max_length=30,validators=[alphanumeric])
  genre = models.CharField(max_length=30,validators=[alphanumeric])
  language = models.CharField(max_length=30,validators=[alphanumeric])
  image = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
  def validate(self):
      if Song.objects.filter(artist__iexact=self.artist).exists():
          raise ValidationError('This artist already exists.')
```

Also, check this [form](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/how-to-make-field-case-insensitive/6918)

Comment: Thank You So Much I implemented this and it worked for my project ... Sorry I am replying this late I forgot earlier ;(